# Source Control advice across multiple developers using a shared folder

Tags: .net, git, version-control

I am looking for some general advice on source control.  Currently we have multiple developers running from a shared drive (connected to IIS) - Dev platform (.NET).

We are looking to implement source control via bit bucket, but my question is.  Does each developer need their own instance of the application code or can they still run from a share?  The issue being that when making edits, source control or not, they are editing the same environment (dev).

Should it be that they have their own instance (this is a big application) locally or via their own share and then changed deployed to a central area once completed and ready for test.

Obviously the second concept is a lot more work to deploy but as we scale i would prefer the best option.

Your feedback and guidance would be greatly received.

Comment: Source control is designed to allow multiple developers to work on source code independently from their own machines and merge changes at appropriate times. Shared drives are not. Use source control.

Comment: Thanks, i understand that.  But with this being web application, when they save the file they can refresh and see the change.  Having local copies would mean they would need IIS on their PC and run the application directly from there.   Or is it best to have source control setup so that as its checked in, it webhooks to the dev platform so they can see their code in action,

Comment: Developers should always have a local environment that they can rapidly iterate against. In addition, changes made to source control should frequently be pushed, built, and deployed to shared environment so that it can be tested in its integrated form.

Answer (score 0):

Each developer needs to have their own clone of the entire source code. That is how Git works, and is widely accepted as best practice.

Comment: Thanks, i understand that.  But with this being web application, when they save the file they can refresh and see the change.  Having local copies would mean they would need IIS on their PC and run the application directly from there.   Or is it best to have source control setup so that as its checked in, it webhooks to the dev platform so they can see their code in action,

Comment: It is common practice for developers to run their own web server (on their own PC). It's the only thing that scales (to more developers). You can install IIS on the developer machine. Or each developer can have IIS running in a VM on their machine. Or you can use Docker. https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-iis